# How to implement the similar effects like iOS SplitView in flutter

Tags: flutter, splitview

SplitView provides better experience when using landscape orientation or tablet devices. 
iOS [UISplitViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller) class and Android [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) have the similar effects when orientation changed to landscape. 
looks like this [img](https://developer.android.com/images/fundamentals/fragments.png).
Then using flutter how can I implement such a SplitView?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial from FilledStacks on how to handle different screen sizes along with different orientations.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udsysUj-X4w

Written version here: https://www.filledstacks.com/post/building-a-responsive-ui-architecture-in-flutter/

The same guy also wrote a Flutter package to help dealing with screen size and orientations stuff so you can have a responsive design.

Link to repo:
https://github.com/FilledStacks/responsive_builder

So if I understand your question, you can achieve the same results of a master/detail view using the same concept.